# Comunicación Python con PLC. ¿Estoy utilizando la librería cpppo y únicamente soy capaz de leer la marca del PLC, no puedo acceder a los tags?

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando capturar datos de un PLC de OMRON, buscando en la red he encontrado información sobre una librería de python 'cpppo'. Haciendo uso de esa librera consigo leer la marca del PLC, en mi caso un NJ de OMRON.

He encontrado muchos ejemplos de comunicación con PLC de Rockwell y no se donde esta la diferencia pero con un PLC de NJ de OMRON no consigo leer los tags ¿no se por donde tirar?

En este aspecto ¿me podríais hechar una mano?

Un ejemplo que he encontrado es este, y al parecer funciona con lo PLC RsLogic. A mi con OMRON, no me funciona aunque haya cambiado la IP y el nombre del tag.

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple
host = "192.168.3.144"
x, = proxy_simple(host).read(("X"))
print (x)
```

Cambiando el Tag X por la siguiente codigo:

```
x, = proxy_simple(host).read([('@1/1/7','SSTRING')] )
```

Obtengo la marca del PLC con la que quiero comunicarme:

`['NJ501-1400']`

Pero si intento leer un tag siempre recibo como respuesta un NONE:

```
x, = proxy_simple(host).read(("SERVICE_MODE"))
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema no estaba en el código Python sino en la configuración del Tag en el PLC.

Los tags que se quieran leer hay que configurar los como Publish_only.

Gracias por todo.